# Google Play In-App Billing and Web

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an app that uses Google Play In-App billing.  This functions correctly, we have a subscription and this subscription can only be processed from within the app.

We also allow the users to check the same information from our website.

We are wondering if there is a way to get status of the subscription of the in-app billing from Google via the web.  From in app billing, we know the following information about the order:

purchaseToken,
packageName,
purchaseState,
orderId,
purchaseTime,
productId

Basically we would want to know if the subscription was still active from the web without using the In app billing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a Purchase Status API to get the status of the in-app billing from Google via http.

> Google Play provides an HTTP-based Purchase Status API that lets you remotely query the status of a specific in-app product or subscription, or cancel an active subscription. The API is designed to be used from your backend servers as a way of securely managing in-app products and subscriptions, as well as extending and integrating them with other services.

You can get an overview on the [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html) and a reference on [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1_1/#Inapppurchases).